# styledmarkers on a google map now all change to style of last marker added since 21 Nov 12

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a map which calls the Gabriel Schneider StyledMarker code.
http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmarker/src/StyledMarker.js

Since today they now behave differently on maps and the example code does not behave as predicted.

Previously you could add bubble markers with 'A' and 'B' shown as the text. Now the first one shows 'A' if created on its own, but if a second marker is added with 'B' as the text the first one also changes to 'B'. (Similarly colours are changed).

Use his simple example to display the problem
http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmarker/examples/simple.htm

the three markers should be different.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new version of the Google Maps API v3 was released.  If you specify version 3.9, it still works:

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_styledmarker_examples_simple_v39.html

v3.10 does not work:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Versioning

Which will be an issue for anyone using this library when v3.9 is retired in about 6 months, unless v3.10 and 3.11 get fixed...

[Created issue](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4594) in the Google Maps API v3 issue tracker

Answer (score 7):

As of Nov 26, 2012 a partial fix was made to StyledMarker.js to make it work better with API v3.10.
The link:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmarker/src/StyledMarker.js"></script>
```

However it only fixes 2 out of 3 problems:

- Color of marker and text in marker now work fine with v3.10
- However the size of the marker is still overwritten with each additional marker added.

I updated the [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4594) in the Google Maps API v3 issue tracker for this and hope it will be fixed as well soon.